# Cannot install chromium or chrome inside 12.04 LTS

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I am new to ubuntu and linux, i am not able to install chrome from the software center it gives me these errors:-

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

chromium-browser: Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is to be installed
                  Depends: libudev0 (>= 147) but 175-0ubuntu9.4 is to be installed
                  Depends: libx11-6 (>= 2:1.4.99.1) but 2:1.4.99.1-0ubuntu2.3 is to be installed
                  Depends: libxcomposite1 (>= 1:0.3-1) but 1:0.4.3-2build1 is to be installed
                  Depends: libxdamage1 (>= 1:1.1) but 1:1.1.3-2build1 is to be installed
                  Depends: libxfixes3 (>= 1:5.0) but 1:5.0-4ubuntu4.4 is to be installed
                  Depends: libxi6 (>= 2:1.2.99.4) but 2:1.7.1.901-1ubuntu1~precise3 is to be installed
                  Depends: libxrandr2 (>= 2:1.2.99.2) but 2:1.3.2-2ubuntu0.3 is to be installed
                  Depends: libxss1 but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but 1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu4 is to be installed
```

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: thanks a lot ! this fixed can you tell more about what was the problem?

Comment: The problem was that some additional packages were to be installed. For some reason with chrome and chromium they do not install automatically on first install of these browsers.

Comment: I will convert it to an answer not to leave it unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run in terminal

```
 sudo apt-get install -f
```

the browser should install OK.

Comment: Short but effective :)